# Magento 1.9.2 Add layer navigation to advance search

Tags: magento-1.9, layered-navigation, advanced-search, layer

I have followed following 3 steps for advanced search layer navigation, but it is not working. Any idea/suggestion OR How to implement layer navigation in advanced search?

**1) In our local.xml under catalogsearch_advanced_result tag add.**

```
<reference name="left">
      <block type="catalogsearch/layer" name="catalogsearch.leftnav" after="currency" template="catalog/layer/view.phtml"/>
 </reference>
```

**2) Override prepareProductCollection function of catalogsearch/model/Layer.php with**

```
public function prepareProductCollection($collection){

    if(Mage::helper('catalogsearch')->getQuery()->getQueryText())//for normal search we get the value from query string q=searchtext
        return parent::prepareProductCollection($collection);
    else{

        $collection->addAttributeToSelect(Mage::getSingleton('catalog/config')->getProductAttributes());
        /**
         * make sure you cross check the $_REQUEST with $attributes
         */
        $attributes = Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product')->getAttributes();

        Mage::log(print_r($_REQUEST,1));
        foreach($attributes as $attribute){
            $attribute_code = $attribute->getAttributeCode();
            //Mage::log("--->>". $attribute_code);
            if($attribute_code == "price")//since i am not using price attribute
                continue;

            if (empty($_REQUEST[$attribute_code])){
                //Mage::log("nothing found--> $attribute_code");
                continue;
            }
            if(!empty($_REQUEST[$attribute_code]) && is_array($_REQUEST[$attribute_code]))
                $collection->addAttributeToFilter($attribute_code, array('in' => $_REQUEST[$attribute_code]));
            else
            if(!empty($_REQUEST[$attribute_code]))
                $collection->addAttributeToFilter($attribute_code, array('like' => "%" . $_REQUEST[$attribute_code] . "%"));
        }

        $collection->setStore(Mage::app()->getStore())
        ->addMinimalPrice()
        ->addFinalPrice()
        ->addTaxPercents()
        ->addStoreFilter()
        ->addUrlRewrite();

        //Mage::log($collection->getSelect()->__toString());

        Mage::getSingleton('catalogsearch/advanced')->prepareProductCollection($collection);    
        Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_status')->addVisibleFilterToCollection($collection);
        Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_visibility')->addVisibleInSearchFilterToCollection($collection);
    }

    return $this;
}
```

**3) Override getProductCollection, getSearchCriterias function of catalogsearch/model/Advanced.php with**

```
public function getProductCollection(){

    if (is_null($this->_productCollection)) {
        $this->_productCollection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalogsearch/advanced_collection')
            ->addAttributeToSelect(Mage::getSingleton('catalog/config')->getProductAttributes())
            ->addMinimalPrice()
            ->addStoreFilter();
            Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_status')->addVisibleFilterToCollection($this->_productCollection);
            Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_visibility')->addVisibleInSearchFilterToCollection($this->_productCollection);

        if(isset($_GET['cat']) && is_numeric($_GET['cat'])) 
            $this->_productCollection->addCategoryFilter(Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($_GET['cat']),true);
    }
    return $this->_productCollection;
}

public function getSearchCriterias()
{
    $search = parent::getSearchCriterias();
    /* display category filtering criteria */
    if(isset($_GET['cat']) && is_numeric($_GET['cat'])) {
        $category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($_GET['cat']);
        $search[] = array('name'=>'Category','value'=>$category->getName());
    }
    return $search;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Create new file in local or override Layer model in local module
app/code/local/Mage/CatalogSearch/Model/Layer.php file and Change **prepareProductCollection** function

```
    public function prepareProductCollection($collection)
    {
        if(Mage::helper('catalogsearch')->getQuery()->getQueryText())
        {
            $collection->addAttributeToSelect(Mage::getSingleton('catalog/config')->getProductAttributes())
            ->addSearchFilter(Mage::helper('catalogsearch')->getQuery()->getQueryText())
            ->setStore(Mage::app()->getStore())
            ->addMinimalPrice()
            ->addFinalPrice()
            ->addTaxPercents()
            ->addStoreFilter()
            ->addUrlRewrite();
        }
        else
        {
            $collection->addAttributeToSelect(Mage::getSingleton('catalog/config')->getProductAttributes());
            $attributes = Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product')->getAttributes();
            foreach($attributes as $attribute)
            {
                $attribute_code = $attribute->getAttributeCode();
                if($attribute_code == "price")
                continue;
                if (empty($_REQUEST[$attribute_code])){continue;}
                if(!empty($_REQUEST[$attribute_code]) && is_array($_REQUEST[$attribute_code]))
                    $collection->addAttributeToFilter($attribute_code, array('in' => $_REQUEST[$attribute_code]));
                else
                if(!empty($_REQUEST[$attribute_code]))
                $collection->addAttributeToFilter($attribute_code, array('like' => "%" . $_REQUEST[$attribute_code] . "%"));
            }
            $collection->setStore(Mage::app()->getStore())
            ->addMinimalPrice()
            ->addFinalPrice()
            ->addTaxPercents()
            ->addStoreFilter()
            ->addUrlRewrite();
            Mage::getSingleton('catalogsearch/advanced')->prepareProductCollection($collection);    
        }
        Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_status')->addVisibleFilterToCollection($collection);
        Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_visibility')->addVisibleInSearchFilterToCollection($collection);
        return $this;
    }
```

After that do same with app/code/local/Mage/CatalogSearch/Model/Advanced.php and change **getProductCollection** and **getSearchCriterias** functions

```
    public function getProductCollection()
    {
        if (is_null($this->_productCollection)) {
            $this->_productCollection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalogsearch/advanced_collection')
            ->addAttributeToSelect(Mage::getSingleton('catalog/config')->getProductAttributes())
            ->addMinimalPrice()
            ->addStoreFilter();
            Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_status')->addVisibleFilterToCollection($this->_productCollection);
            Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_visibility')->addVisibleInSearchFilterToCollection($this->_productCollection);
            if(isset($_GET['cat']) && is_numeric($_GET['cat']))
            $this->_productCollection->addCategoryFilter(Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($_GET['cat']),true);
        }
        return $this->_productCollection;
    }
    public function getSearchCriterias()
    {
        $search = $this->_searchCriterias;
        if(isset($_GET['cat']) && is_numeric($_GET['cat'])){
            $category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($_GET['cat']);
            $search[] = array('name'=>'Category','value'=>$category->getName());
        }
        return $search;
    }
```

Here in below layer navigation is prepared for advance search product collection now must display that layer navigation using theme xml file so edit your theme's c**atalogsearch.xml** file and add below code in  tag.

```
<reference name="left">
  <block type="catalogsearch/layer" name="catalogsearch.leftnav" after="currency" template="catalog/layer/view.phtml"/>
</reference>
```

For More information
visit this [link](https://newsinfo-blog.blogspot.in/2016/05/add-layered-navigation-to-advance.html)

Comment: It's working like charm!

Answer (score 0):

To show the layered navigation in advanced search you have to make some changes in  core file.

Follow this link I have use the same process and it is working fine.

https://newsinfo-blog.blogspot.in/2016/05/add-layered-navigation-to-advance.html

Comment: Consider adding the information from that link to your post, link's are getting expired, page's closed.

Comment: Just looking for visitors, it sucks :/

Answer (score 0):

For add layer navigation to advance search follow the below steps:
    1- In below layer navigation is prepared for advance search product collection now must display that layer navigation using theme xml file so edit your theme catalogsearch.xml file and add below code under  tag.

```
    <reference name="left">
      <block type="catalogsearch/layer" name="catalogsearch.leftnav" after="currency" template="catalog/layer/view.phtml"/>
    </reference>

2. Override prepareProductCollection function of catalogsearch/model/Layer.php with this

    public function prepareProductCollection($collection)
    {   
        $bac= Mage::helper('catalogsearch')->getQuery()->getQueryText();
        if($bac)
        {
            $collection->addAttributeToSelect(Mage::getSingleton('catalog/config')->getProductAttributes())
            ->addSearchFilter(Mage::helper('catalogsearch')->getQuery()->getQueryText())
            ->setStore(Mage::app()->getStore())
            ->addMinimalPrice()
            ->addFinalPrice()
            ->addTaxPercents()
            ->addStoreFilter()
            ->addUrlRewrite();

        } 
        else 
        {

            $collection->addAttributeToSelect(Mage::getSingleton('catalog/config')->getProductAttributes());
            $attributes = Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product')->getAttributes();
            foreach($attributes as $attribute)
            {
                $attribute_code = $attribute->getAttributeCode();
                if($attribute_code == "price")
                continue;
                if (empty($_REQUEST[$attribute_code])){continue;}
                if(!empty($_REQUEST[$attribute_code]) && is_array($_REQUEST[$attribute_code]))
                    $collection->addAttributeToFilter($attribute_code, array('in' => $_REQUEST[$attribute_code]));
                else
                if(!empty($_REQUEST[$attribute_code]))
                $collection->addAttributeToFilter($attribute_code, array('like' => "%" . $_REQUEST[$attribute_code] . "%"));
            }
            $collection->setStore(Mage::app()->getStore())
            ->addMinimalPrice()
            ->addFinalPrice()
            ->addTaxPercents()
            ->addStoreFilter()
            ->addUrlRewrite();
            Mage::getSingleton('catalogsearch/advanced')->prepareProductCollection($collection);    
        }
        Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_status')->addVisibleFilterToCollection($collection);
        Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_visibility')->addVisibleInSearchFilterToCollection($collection);
        return $this;
    }

3. Than after changing getProductCollection and getSearchCriterias function as below in app/code/core/Mage/CatalogSearch/Model/Advanced.php file.

<?php 
public function getProductCollection()
{
    if (is_null($this->_productCollection)) {
        $this->_productCollection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalogsearch/advanced_collection')
        ->addAttributeToSelect(Mage::getSingleton('catalog/config')->getProductAttributes())
        ->addMinimalPrice()
        ->addStoreFilter();
        Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_status')->addVisibleFilterToCollection($this->_productCollection);
        Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_visibility')->addVisibleInSearchFilterToCollection($this->_productCollection);
        if(isset($_GET['cat']) && is_numeric($_GET['cat']))
        $this->_productCollection->addCategoryFilter(Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($_GET['cat']),true);
    }
    return $this->_productCollection;
}

public function getSearchCriterias()
{
    $search = $this->_searchCriterias;
    if(isset($_GET['cat']) && is_numeric($_GET['cat'])){
        $category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($_GET['cat']);
        $search[] = array('name'=>'Category','value'=>$category->getName());
    }
    return $search;
}
```